# Is it possible the datagrid short the collection of the view model?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

I have a `DataGrid` that binds to an `ObservableCollection` in the `viewModel`. I wanted to sort the items of the `DataGrid` by many columns, so I would like the `ObservableCollection` in the `Viewmodel` to have the items in the same order. Otherwise, using the `SelectedIndex` property in the `ViewModel`, it could select incorrect items.

To do it, I try to use the `mode TwoWay` in the view, but the collection is not sorted in the view model.

So I would like to know if it is possible to sync this.

Comment: And where all this elements must be after you "short" them? :)

Comment: Alvaro, perhaps you mean 'sort'?

Comment: unclear question, what do you mean by shorting ? do you want to reduce number of columns, or change the order of rows meaning sorting them ?